# Поиск индекса минимального значения в Бинарном Дереве

Tags: java, алгоритм, структуры

Мне удалось написать алгоритм, который с помощью рекурсии позволяет пройтись по всем элементам дерева и найти минимальное значение, но главная цель задачи состоит именно в поиске индекса минимального значения (глубина минимального узла). Кто может подсказать как это осуществить?

Вот код класса `Node` (элемент бинарного дерева) :

```
сlass Node{

//vars
Node left;
Node right;
int val;


public Node(Node left, Node right, int val) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.val = val;
}

//functions
public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}


public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}


public int getVal() {
    return val;
}


}
```

А вот класс, в котором происходит поиск мин. значения :

```
class App{

//vars
static int min;
static Node NODE;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    //бинарное дерево в представлении объектов 
    Node X = new Node(null,null,-12);
    Node I = new Node(null,X,-3);
    Node H = new Node(null,null,-700);
    Node G = new Node(null,null,-5);
    Node F = new Node(null,null,-10);
    Node D = new Node(H,I,-100);
    Node E = new Node(F,G,-2);
    Node C = new Node(E,D,3);
    Node B = new Node(null,null,1);
    Node A = new Node(B,C,6);

    NODE = A; 
    min = A.getVal(); //min = 6

    //поиск мин. значения
    calculateNode(A);

}


 public static void calculateNode(Node node){

   if(node.getLeft() != null) calculateLeftNode(node.getLeft());
   if(node.getRight()!= null) calculateRightNode(node.getRight());

}

public static void calculateLeftNode(Node node){

        int value = node.getVal();
        if(min > value) min = value;

        calculateNode(node);
}

public static void calculateRightNode(Node node){

       int value = node.getVal();
       if(min > value) min = value;

       calculateNode(node);
}


}
```

Вот графическое представление этого дерева : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А под индексом минимального значения вы что понимаете?

Comment: @PavelParshin Например, индекс нужного числа - это 4 (отсчет идет с 1, а не с 0). Ну и "нужное число", это элемент древа H(-700)

Comment: То есть уровень/глубина минимального узла?

Comment: @PavelParshin Да. Но вот только проблема в том, что я пока не могу понять, как его найти. У меня только идея с HashMap есть, но не знаю, выйдет ли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int minNodeLevel = -1;
static int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

public static void findMinNode(Node root) {
    calculateNode(root, 1);
}

private static void calculateNode(Node node, int nodeLevel) {
   if (node == null) { return; }

   int value = node.getVal();
   if (minValue > value) {
        minValue = value;
        minNodeLevel = nodeLevel;
   }

   calculateNode(node.getLeft(), nodeLevel + 1);
   calculateNode(node.getRight(), nodeLevel + 1);
}
```